# How to convert a directory of jpg files to a pdf with filenames as bookmarks?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, tools, image-viewers, pdf-bookmarks

I have a directory of jpg files that are scans of my handwritten notes.  How do I convert them to a single pdf file that has the filenames as bookmarks?

(I eventually also want to add ocr.  As mentioned online, we can convert the .jpg files to a .pdf using "img2pdf *.jp* --output combined.pdf", and then we can add ocr using "ocrmypdf combined.pdf combined_ocr.pdf".  My question is mainly about how to also make sure the pdf file has bookmarks (created from filenames) so that the document is easy to navigate.)

Comment: pdftk allows to change/add bookmarks on the command line. Possibly, you may merge multiple PDF's and update their bookmarks into a merged PDF. Also Ghostscript works with pdfmarks: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17065/add-and-edit-bookmarks-to-a-pdf-file